# How to recover wordpress installation?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I installed wordpress on my web hosting for building my website using wordpress. Accidentally, one of my team member deleted all the files of the installation and now i am unable to do either a fresh install or recover the last install.I have a cpanel powered linux hosting. When i try to install wordpress again it asks me to remove the existing installation and when i try to remove the existing installation it says that it was unable to find the installation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you asking support from your hoster , opening a ticket on it

Comment: Upload the WP files again, update the wp-config.php file to match your existing DB name / user details.

Comment: you have cpanel right, then you can go to public_html and manually delete the existing installation